# Form with 2 jquery date-picker action

Tags: php, jquery, forms, datepicker

I have a form with a Check-In and a Check-Out that use a jqyery date-picker
Check In

Check Out

Date picker script is:

```
  // datepicker
    tjq('.datepicker-wrap input').each(function() {
        var minDate = tjq(this).data("min-date");
        if (typeof minDate == "undefined") {
            minDate = 0;
        }
        tjq(this).datepicker({

            showOn: 'button',
            buttonImage: 'images/icon/blank.png',
            buttonText: '',
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            changeYear: false,
            /*showOtherMonths: true,*/
            minDate: minDate,
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
closeText: 'Inchide',
        prevText: '&#xAB; Luna precedenta',
        nextText: 'Luna urmÄatoare &#xBB;',
        currentText: 'Azi',
        monthNames: ['Ianuarie','Februarie','Martie','Aprilie','Mai','Iunie',
        'Iulie','August','Septembrie','Octombrie','Noiembrie','Decembrie'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Ian', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Mai', 'Iun',
        'Iul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        dayNames: ['Duminica', 'Luni', 'Marti', 'Miercuri', 'Joi', 'Vineri', 'Sambata'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dum', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mie', 'Joi', 'Vin', 'Sam'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Du','Lu','Ma','Mi','Jo','Vi','Sa'],
        weekHeader: 'Sapt',
        firstDay: 1,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
            beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
                var themeClass = tjq(input).parent().attr("class").replace("datepicker-wrap", "");
                tjq('#ui-datepicker-div').attr("class", "");
                tjq('#ui-datepicker-div').addClass("ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all");
                tjq('#ui-datepicker-div').addClass(themeClass);
            }
        });
    });
```

Calendars are

```
<input type="text" name="date1" class="input-text full-width hasDatepicker" id="date1"> 
<input type="text" name="date2" class="input-text full-width hasDatepicker" id="date2">
```

How can I improve the jquery date-picker so when I click one of the fields (Check In or Check Out) so both of them pop-up and autoselect the 'Check Out' to be with 1 day after Check In'?

Comment: i dont know where to start :(. All i did on this i have put the translated text.

Answer (score 1):

I played a little in JSFiddle and think I figured out what you need. This should help. Modify to your needs:

http://jsfiddle.net/fpcuhv35/

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="date1" class="datepicker" id="date1">
<input type="text" name="date2" class="datepicker" id="date2">
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#date2").datepicker();
    $("#date1").datepicker({
        onSelect: function(){
            var fecha = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            $("#date2").datepicker("setDate", new Date(fecha.getTime()));
            $("#date2").datepicker("setDate", "+15d");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@solar411 Wanted to add that the second setDate was just adding 15 to the current date. This modified JSFiddle will add one day to the perviously selected date.

http://jsfiddle.net/fpcuhv35/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#date2").datepicker();
    $("#date1").datepicker({
        onSelect: function(){
            var fecha = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            $("#date2").datepicker("setDate", new Date(fecha.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I have tried and did not work on my side, DOes it make sense if the id of my calendars are <input type="text" name="date1" class="input-text full-width hasDatepicker" id="date1">
<input type="text" name="date2" class="input-text full-width hasDatepicker" id="date2">

Comment: @RazvanBaba I need to see more of your code to be able to properly diagnose. The main thing that matters is that the $("#date1") (div id) matches that of your input.